# Adding custom HTML with dedicated CSS Styling to existing theme on Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I've created a bit of custom code, as my friends wanted a cool hovering effect on their homepage. Since I'm quite the newbie, I was really proud I could create this flexbox-based container from scratch (granted, with a bit of help from a youtube tutorial).  Now I'm struggling to integrate this in the existing blockstructure of my theme. I'm running neve as a theme, and want to replace the uppermost block (which is now simply holding a background image) with my custom HTML, styled with my custom CSS. I'm certain this should be possible, and am convinced that it's something rather simple that I'm just not getting at the moment. Please haelp a brother out. For reference, this is the site i'm trying to customize: [www.thenewport.org](http://www.thenewport.org) (it's just about the frontpage picture I'm trying to replace, the one with the 5 buildings).

Here's the element I made myself: https://codepen.io/janstanna/pen/VwmKNNJ

html:

```
  <div class ="box-zeeland" > Zeeland   </div>
  <div class ="box-normandie" > Normandy </div>
  <div class ="box-roffa" > Rotterdam </div>
  <div class ="box-Valencia" > Valencia  </div>
  <div class ="box-Adam" > Amsterdam </div>
<div class ="overlay" > </div>
</div> </span>
```

CSS:

````
*{
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  }


  
  .container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 1066px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 100px auto;
    display: flex;
    background; #ddd; 
    font-family: Helvetica;
    color: white; 
    vertical-align: bottom;
    justify-content: bottom;
    align-self: flex-end;
}





.overlay {
    border: 2px #ddd;
    z-index: 10;
    font-size: 90px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 300; top: 300; right: 300; bottom: 300;
    /* top: 0; left: 0; */
    /* width: 100%; height: 100%; */
    /* display: -webkit-flex; */
    /* flex-align: center; flex-pack: center; */
    /* display: block; */
    /* clear: both; */
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-weight: 600px;

  }

  
  .box-zeeland {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    background-image: url(https://elnuevopuerto.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Zeeland_header_The_New_Port_Verdonkerd.jpg);
    border: 3px solid #ddd;
    font-size: 30px;
    flex:1;
    transition: 1s;
    text-align: center;
    align-self: flex-end;
    order: 3;

  }
  
  .box-zeeland:hover{
    flex:3;
    background-image: url(https://elnuevopuerto.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Zeeland_648x1066_DARK.jpg);
    order: 3;
  }

  .box-normandie {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    background-image: url(https://elnuevopuerto.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/LNP_648_DARK.jpg);
    border: 3px solid #ddd;
    font-size: 30px;
    flex:1;
    transition: 1s;
    text-align: center;
    align-self: flex-end;
    order: 1;

  }

  .box-normandie:hover{
    flex:2;
    background-image: url(https://lenouveauport.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/IMG_0037.jpg)
    order: 1;
  }

  .box-roffa{
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  background-image:url(https://elnuevopuerto.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/rotterdam_Website_warmer_324_Verdonkerd.jpg);
  border: 3px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 30px;
  flex:1;
  transition: 1s;
  text-align: center;
  order:2;
}

.box-roffa:hover {
  flex:3;
  background-image: url(https://elnuevopuerto.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/rotterdam_Website_warmer_648_DARK.jpg);
  order: 2;
}

.box-Valencia{
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  background-image: url(https://elnuevopuerto.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/ElNuveopuerto_Header_Valencia_324_Verdonkerd.jpg);
  border: 3px solid #ddd;

  font-size: 30px;
  flex:1;
  transition: 1s;
  text-align: center;
  order: 4;
}


.box-Valencia:hover {
  flex:3;
  background-image: url(https://elnuevopuerto.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/ElNuveopuerto_Header_Valencia_648_DARK.jpg);
  order: 4;

}

.box-Adam{
height: 100%;
padding: 0px;
background-image:url(https://elnuevopuerto.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/DNPAMS001_324x1066_header_Verdonkerd.jpg);
border: 3px solid #ddd;
font-size: 30px;
flex:1;
transition: 1s;
text-align: center;
order: 5;

}


.box-Adam:hover{
  flex:3;
  background-image: url(https://elnuevopuerto.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/DNPAMS001_648_Header_DARK.jpg);
  order: 5;

}


  </style>```








  

I hope someone can help me, I've been stuck for a couple of days now! Thank in advance!
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just tried running your code on a fresh WordPress install with the Neve theme installed.

Its all working correctly, except do not use `.container` as a class for the flex box, instead use something like `.container-flex`.

`.container` is already assigned to some HTML in the Neve theme.

I was unable to gain access to the site you want to use this on. But if you just need to add this onto a page, use the Custom HTML block, paste in your HTML code and save the page.

```
<span> <div class ="container-flex">
<div class ="box-zeeland" > Zeeland   </div>
<div class ="box-normandie" > Normandy </div>
<div class ="box-roffa" > Rotterdam </div>
<div class ="box-Valencia" > Valencia  </div>
<div class ="box-Adam" > Amsterdam </div>
<div class ="overlay" > </div>
</div> </span>
```

Then click on Customize > Additional CSS, and paste your CSS code in there and click Publish. Then your code should work as intended.

Comment: Thanks man! That worked like a charm!!! Renaming it to container-flex was the key i didnt see! You're the best!

Comment: No problem. happy to help. Please mark this question as answered if you're happy with it.